# How does loss.backward() work for batches?

Tags: python, pytorch, batch-processing, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

So I am training a DDQN to play connect four at the moment. At each state, the network predicts the action the best action and moves accordingly. The code looks basically like follows:

```
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        for i in range(batch_size):
                while game is not finished:
                        action = select_action(state)
                        new_state = play_move(state, action)
                        pred, target = get_pred_target(state, new_state, action)
                        preds = torch.cat([preds, pred])
                        targets = torch.cat([targets, target)]
        loss = loss_fn(preds, targets)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

While training, the network is getting a little bit better, but nowhere as good as I would expect. Thinking about it, I am wondering now, whether I have actually correctly implemented the loss.backward() call. The point is, I am saving all the predictions and targets for each move in the tensors preds and targets. However, I am not tracking the states, that have led to these predictions and targets. But isn't that necessary for the backward propagation, or is this information somehow saved?

Thank you very much!